# Two inequalities with parameters $a,b,c>0$ such that $ca+ab+bc+abc\leq 4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$ be such that $bc+ca+ab+abc\leq 4$.  Prove the following inequalities:
>
> (a) $8(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq 3(b+c)(c+a)(a+b)$, and
>
> (b) $\dfrac{1}{a^2}+\dfrac{1}{b^2}+\dfrac{1}{c^2}+\dfrac{2}{a^2b}+\dfrac{2}{b^2c}+\dfrac{2}{c^2a}\geq 9$.
>
> Prove also that the unique equality case for both inequalities is given by $a=b=c=1$.

Below are some probably useful or relevant results.

- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1241430p6342224
- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h284290p1535893
- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h608971p3619202
- https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1804479p11995588
- [If $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$, then $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}\leq 3\leq a+b+c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461934/if-abbccaabc-4-then-sqrtab-sqrtbc-sqrtca-leq-3-leq-abc)

Techniques used in solving the inequalities in these links may prove useful in proving our inequalities.

**Attempt.**  In the simplest case, $a=b=c=:t$, we have $t^3+3t^2-4\leq 0$, whence $0<t\leq 1$.  Therefore, the inequalities (a) and (b) become
$$24t^2\geq 24t^3$$
and
$$\frac{3}{t^2}+\frac{6}{t^3}\geq 9\,,$$
which are obviously true.  How to prove these inequalities in general?

Comment: Shouldn't the two inequalities be asked separately?

Comment: @ArnaudD.  One inequality is much easier than the other.  That inequality alone is not interesting enough to deserve a separate question.  The source I obtained the inequalities put them both in the same question.  I will disclose the source in a week.  (If you look at my questions lately, you would probably be able to guess where the source came from.  My reason for not posting the solutions is that the right persons should post them.)

Comment: I found your [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825783/problems-regarding-inequality), and honestly I would have the same objection there.

Comment: How many hours or days have you spent to prove this problem? I was just curious. :)

Comment: @lonestudent  Me?  I solved Part (b) easily.  The idea is very similar to the "attempt" in the question with a small tweak.  For Part (a), I didn't solve it.  I tried Lagrange multipliers but that was too complicated.  I may have spent a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inequality.

Let $a=kx$, $b=ky$ and $c=kz$ such that $k>0$ and $xy+xz+yz+xyz=4.$

Thus, the condition gives $$k^2(xy+xz+yz)+k^3xyz\leq xy+xz+yz+xyz$$ or
$$(k-1)((k+1)(xy+xz+yz)+(k^2+k+1)xyz)\leq0$$ or $$k\leq1.$$
Thus, we need to prove that $$8(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq3k(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$$ and since $0<k\leq1$,  it's enough to prove that $$8(x^2+y^2+z^2)\geq3(x+y)(x+z)(y+z).$$
Now, rewrite the new condition in the following form:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+2}=4$$ and let $x=\frac{2p}{q+r}$ and $y=\frac{2q}{p+r},$ where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are positives.

Thus, $z=\frac{2r}{p+q}$ and after this substitution we obtain something obvious.

But it's better to prove before that $$x+y+z\geq xy+xz+yz,$$ for which we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2p}{q+r}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{4pq}{(p+r)(q+r)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}p(p+q)(p+r)\geq2\sum_{cyc}pq(p+q)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(p^3-p^2q-p^2r+pqr)\geq0,$$ which is true by Schur.

Now, since $$1\geq\frac{xy+xz+yz}{x+y+z},$$ it's enough to prove that $$8(x^2+y^2+z^2)(xy+xz+yz)\geq3(x+y+z)(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(5x^3y+5x^3z-6x^2y^2-4x^2yz)\geq0,$$ which is true by Muirhead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach using Lagrange multipliers.

For the first part, we can write the problem as \begin{align}\min&\quad8(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\\\text{s.t.}&\quad ab+ac+bc+abc=4-\epsilon\\&\quad a,b,c>0\quad\land\quad0\le\epsilon<4.\end{align} Then we have $\mathcal L=f-\lambda g$ where $f(a,b,c)=8(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ and $g(a,b,c)=ab+ac+bc+abc-(4-\epsilon)$. The partial derivatives are \begin{align}\mathcal L_a&=16a-3(b+c)(2a+b+c)-\lambda(b+c+bc)\\\mathcal L_b&=16b-3(a+c)(2b+a+c)-\lambda(a+c+ac)\\\mathcal L_c&=16c-3(a+b)(2c+a+b)-\lambda(a+b+ab)\\\mathcal L_\lambda&=ab+ac+bc+abc-(4-\epsilon).\end{align} Next, we have \begin{align}\mathcal L_a-\mathcal L_b&=0\implies16+3(a+b)+\lambda(1+c)=0,a=b\\\mathcal L_a-\mathcal L_c&=0\implies16+3(a+c)+\lambda(1+b)=0,a=c\\\mathcal L_b-\mathcal L_c&=0\implies16+3(b+c)+\lambda(1+a)=0,b=c,\end{align} so without loss of generality we have $a=b$. Letting $c=ka$ yields $f(a,b,c)=8(2+k^2)a^2-6(1+k)^2a^3$ and $g(a,b,c)=(1+2k)a^2+ka^3-(4-\epsilon)$. Since $f\to0^+$ as $\epsilon\to4^-$ we aim to find $k,\epsilon$ such that $f\le0$.

Elementary calculus reveals that $f(a;k)$ increases monotonically in the interval $[0,k^*]$ where $k^*=8(2+k^2)/(9(1+k)^2)$, from $0$ to $f(k^*;k)>0$. For $a>k^*$, the function $f(a;k)$ decreases monotonically to $-\infty$, where it meets the axis at $a=3k^*/2$. Notice that positive root of $g$ is largest when $4-\epsilon$ is greatest; that is, $\epsilon=0$. At this value, it suffices to notice that $$g\left(\frac{3k^*}2;k\right)=(1+2k)\left(\frac{4(2+k^2)}{3(1+k)^2}\right)^2+k\left(\frac{4(2+k^2)}{3(1+k)^2}\right)^3-4=(k-1)^2\cdot\frac{P(k)}{Q(k)}$$ where $P,Q$ are polynomials with positive coefficients. As $k>0$ the only solution to $g=0$ is $k=1$, from which it follows that $a=b=c=1$. $\square$

Comment: Does your method work for the second inequality?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I haven't tried the second inequality :P

Comment: I think it does not work. :P :D

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Don't tempt me to solve the second problem, I have more important things to do today!

Comment: OK, OK. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825783/problems-regarding-inequality.  Below are solutions for both parts, some were written by other users in the old thread above.

**Part (a):** [Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825783/problems-regarding-inequality#comment5826536_2825783) by [Truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/552062/truth).

Let $a = \dfrac{2kx}{y+z}$, $b = \dfrac{2ky}{z+x}$, and $c = \dfrac{2kz}{x+y}$, where $x,y,z,k>0$.    From the given condition, we get $k \leqslant  1$ and the required inequality is equivalent to $$96k^2\,\sum_\text{cyc}\, \frac{x^2}{(y+z)^2} \geqslant 72k^3 \prod_\text{cyc}\, \left(\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}\right)\,.$$
This is equivalent to $$4\,\sum_\text{cyc}\, \frac{x^2}{(y+z)^2} \geqslant 3k\,\prod_\text{cyc}\, \left(\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}\right)\,.$$

Because $ k \leqslant 1$, it suffices to show that $$4\,\sum_\text{cyc}\, \frac{x^2}{(y+z)^2} \geqslant 3\, \prod_\text{cyc}\, \left(\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{z+x}\right)\,,$$ However, the last inequality is equivalent to
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\, \frac{\big(2x^4+16xyz^2+6y^2z^2+(2x^2+9xz+9yz+6z^2)(x+y-z)^2\big)(x-y)^2}{(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2} \geqslant 0\,.$$

**Part (b):**  [Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2825809/72152) by [Michael Rozenberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190319/michael-rozenberg).  (@Michael, if you want to use this proof in your own separate answer, then you can remove this solution from my answer here and add it into your own answer.)

By the AM-GM Inequality,
$$4\geq3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}+abc\,,$$ which gives $$abc\leq1\,.$$
Thus, by the AM-GM Inequality again, we obtain
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2}+2\,\sum_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2b}\geq\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}}+\frac{6}{abc}\geq9\,.$$

**Part (b):**  Alternative Proof by Me.

Use the AM-GM Inequality with the constraint inequality, we have
$$4\geq bc+ca+ab+abc\geq 4\,\sqrt[4]{(bc)(ca)(ab)(abc)}=4\,(abc)^{\frac{3}{4}}\,,$$
whence
$$abc\leq 1\,.$$
Now, we have by the AM-GM Inequality that
$$\sum_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2}+2\,\sum_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2b}\geq 9\, \sqrt[9]{\left(\prod_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\,\left(\prod_\text{cyc}\,\frac{1}{a^2b}\right)^2}=\frac{9}{(abc)^{\frac{8}{9}}}\,.$$
As $abc\leq 1$, the required inequality follows immediately.